# attauching stylesheet to a web page on wordpress

Tags: css, wordpress

I'm a newbee to wordpress and I'm trying to attauch to a theme main stylesheet but, I have problems, the styles rules aren't applied to the page.
here is my index.php file so far:

```
<?php
    get_header();
    if (have_posts()):
        while (have_posts()):
            the_post();
        the_title();
        the_excerpt();
        the_author();
        endwhile;
    endif;
    get_sidebar();
    get_footer();
?>
```

here is my functions.php file, that I use for uploading the stylesheet:

```
<?php
function add_theme_scripts() {
    wp_enqueue_style( 'main', get_stylesheet_uri(), false );
}
add_action("wp_enqueue_scripts", "add_theme_scripts");
?>
```

And whatever I have tried to upload styles through blogifno in the head of the header file, but it doesn't work either, the page is shown not styled at all
What is the matter?

Comment: there could be a few issues but start by checking the output sent to the browser (view source on  the webpage) and see if it has been attached. Also check the console for errors, but offhand make sure you have style.css in your theme root folder

Comment: the console tells : 
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500 (Internal Server Error)

Comment: the css file is located in the root of the project

Comment: get_stylesheet_uri() assumes there is a file called style.css in the theme folder root (not in a subfolder) but you should see in the console the location it is looking in

Comment: the console answer
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500 (Internal Server Error). 
the console is looking in exact the same location where the style file is

Comment: and everything works fine with WP installed themes that I got with my WAMP by default

Comment: hmm the 500 error suggests that there is not a file in the exacts location called style.css, you can put the actual path in wp_enqueue script see if it makes a diff